# Assigning a character array to a character array in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am working on a project that requires that I make an array of a certain structure type.  The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
char array[30];
int num;
}structure
```

I have declared an array of these structures like this:

```
structure struct1[5];
```

I passed this structure array to a function which fills the first four elements with a string and a number.  The fifth is left blank.  Later in the program, I pass the array again and try to set the string in the structure to a user determined string using gets().  I am getting this error:

```
438:19: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[30]' from type 'char *'
```

If I need to provide more clarification, please tell me.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Here is what I am doing:

```
typedef struct
{
char array[30];
int num;
}structure;

void fillStructs(structure[]);
void userEditStructs(structure[]);

main()
{
structure myStructs[5];
fillStructs(myStructs);
userEditStructs(myStructs);
return 0;
}

void fillStructs(structure s[])
{
    //code to fill myStructs elements 0-3.
}

void userEditStructs(structure s[])
{
char newArr[30];
int newNum;
printf("Please enter your string:\n\nEntry:\t");
gets(newArr);
printf("Please enter your number:\n\nEntry:\t");
scanf("%i", newNum);
s[5].array = newArr;
s[5].num = newNum;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you're passing the array of structures to the function.

Comment: use strcpy and not operator =

Comment: Never ever use `gets()`. It is dangerous, it is deprecated, it is removed from C++ and should be removed from C too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the code you are probably trying to do something like:

```
struct[4].array = gets(<unknown>);
```

which won't work, as you can't assign the returned  `char*` from `gets` to an array as the compiler says. You are also using `gets`, which is strongly discouraged as it performs no bounds checking. Instead, do the following:

```
fgets(struct[4].array, sizeof(struct[4].array), stdin);
```

which will do proper bounds checking.

Answer (score 3):

you are doing something like this

```
char a[20];
a = "bla";
```

you cant do this.

do `strcpy(a,"bla");` instead. ( `#include <string.h>` )